# Animation nodes execute on a condition

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to make animation node run on a specific frame. I compare the time info with the frame i want the node to execute on, and if they are equal, they return true. But I do not understand how do I execute an action if it returns true.

edit: Okay, so I used expression node to return a value if time info is equal to a specific frame. But is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a node called Switch, you plug in the condition, and 'if true' or 'if false', then connect the output to the rest of your nodes